# 'ZoneDropDown' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a bunch of controls in my .aspx page. Also, the designer is also generating code for those controls.
When i am trying to use any of these controls, i am getting the above mentioned error for all the controls in the page.
I am new to VB.Net. 
please help
thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your code (the designer code, html and vb code)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your page directive at the top of your aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Mater.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>
```

Check to see if the CodeFile property is set to the proper code file.

So if you're working on Test.aspx and your code file is Test.aspx.vb your CodeFile property should be set to Test.aspx.vb and it should Inherit Test.

If the CodeFile is incorrect then you will not be able to access any of the controls because the code behind does not know what page to look on.